# Does gas smell in otherwise perfectly working pilot light gas stove indicate a problem?

Tags: gas, oven

I recently moved into an airbnb with a Wedgewood stove (a narrow white one with four plates and one oven). It seems to work all fine: I can see a blue pilot flame burning at the bottom of the oven, another blue one beneath the hobs, and when I turn the dials, hob and oven come on as expected.

The only issue is that when I open the oven door, there is a strong smell of gas towards the top. I have quite a sensitive nose and can actually smell the gas as soon as I approach the kitchen. The owner says that this smell is normal when the stove has not been used for a while. Are they correct or is there cause to worry? I have used the oven and the smell is still there.

Comment: That must be a *very* old stove. In the US pilot-light stoves were banned in 1990.

Comment: The gas is leaking, is is not coming from the pilots. A very small leak can produce a smell.

Comment: It may indicate that one of the pilot lights is out, or it may indicate a leak. Either way, I wouldn't consider it normal, and if it was mine I'd find it and fix it, or get it fixed. If it hasn't exploded yet it _probably_ won't do so while you're staying there...

Comment: In the US, standard advice upon smelling gas would be to get out of the unit immediately and call gas company emergency line. It could indicate a dangerous situation, such a sign of a connection that may come apart more catastrophically.